# Should I begin with uppercase when placing a sentence inside a apostrophes?

Tags: grammar

Here's an example:

Warren said, 'could you help me remember some English basics?' vs. 
Warren said, 'Could you help me remember some English basics?'

Answer (score 1):

Yes, capitalize.
 Here is a quick reference site:
http://www.fiction-writers-mentor.com/punctuating-dialogue.html

Answer (score 0):

The second of those is the way to do it. *Could* is the first word in the sentence reported, and the first words of sentences in English begin with a capital letter. You would not, however, use a a capital letter if you wrote *Warren asked me if I could help him remember some English basics.*

Answer (score 0):

You always capitalize the first word in a sentence and as the thing in the parenthesis is a sentence then the first word should be capitalized.

The second one is correct.